# Symfony4 Forms - How do you conditionally disable a form field?

Tags: forms, symfony4

So what is the best way to have a form render effectively the same form over and over again, with conditionally disabled fields based on the Entity's property values?

I have an Invoice Entity and need a form for creating the invoice, and also the same form with various fields disabled at various stages of the invoicing process (generated, sent, paid etc).

I think the simplest answer is to disable them dynamically in the twig template via form_row options but surely this will affect server side validation of the form as it is not aware the field has been disabled?

What is the best way to disbale a field based on a value in the database?

### **EDIT 1:**

Changed question from `Dynamically disable a field in the twig template or seperate class for each form?` to `Symfony4 Forms - How do you conditionally disable a form field?`

Comment: You can use [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) (typically the PRE_SET_DATE event) to dynamically modify your form based on entity values.  On the other hand, just using different forms tends to much easier to understand.

Comment: @Cerad. Thanks for the nudge. `PRE_SET_DATE` sent me to the right answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [@Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50436147/symfony4-forms-how-do-you-conditionally-disable-a-form-field?noredirect=1#comment87886703_50436147). The answer is in fact [Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#event-listeners)

In the form type (`App\Form\InvoicesType` for me), add a method call to the end of the builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

    $plus_thirty_days = new \DateTime('+28 days');

    $builder
        ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Clients::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'disabled' => false,
        ) )
        // the event that will handle the conditional field
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            array($this, 'onPreSetData')
        );;
}
```

and then in the same class, create a public method named the same as the string in the array (`onPreSetData` for this example):

```
public function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{

    // get the form
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // get the data if 'reviewing' the information
    /**
     * @var Invoices
     */
    $data = $event->getData();


    // disable field if it has been populated with a client already
    if ( $data->getClient() instanceof Clients )
        $form->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Clients::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'disabled' => true,
        ) );

}
```

From here you can update the field to be any valid [FormType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html) and specify any valid options as you would a normal form element in the From Builder and it will replace the previous one, laving it in the same original position in the form.